# Vagrant - how to configure vagrant ssh when using private interfaces?

Tags: networking, vagrant

I have a multivm vagrantfile setup with 3 vms. 
Two of the vm's have their NAT network interface disabled, and solely use a static ip on an internal interface.

The side effect is that I am no longer able to run `vagrant ssh foo` to connect to the vm's.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  #config.vm.box = "PuppetlabsCent64"
  #config.vm.box_url = "http://puppet-vagrant-boxes.puppetlabs.com/centos-64-x64-vbox4210-nocm.box"
  config.vm.box = "Debian-7-2"
  config.vm.box_url= "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/197673519/debian-7.2.0.box"
  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.
  # config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.45.10"

  # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
  # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
  # your network.
  # config.vm.network :public_network

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant_data"

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
   vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "512"]
  end

     config.vm.define "r", primary: true  do |router|
       router.vm.box = "Debian-7-2"
       router.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.45.11"

     end

     config.vm.define "r1" do |roomate1|
       roomate1.vm.box = "Debian-7-2"
       roomate1.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.45.12"
     end

     config.vm.define "r2" do |roomate2|
       roomate2.vm.box = "Debian-7-2"
       roomate2.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.45.13"
     end

   config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
     vb.customize "post-boot",["controlvm", :id, "setlinkstate1", "off"]
   end

end
```

[This thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/HwqFegoCXOc) in the vagrant user group, gave me the idea to check the [default vagrant config](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/config/default.rb).

I've tried each of the following with no luck

```
 config.vm.define "r", primary: true  do |router|
   router.vm.box = "Debian-7-2"
   router.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.45.11"
   #config.ssh.host "192.168.45.11"
   #router.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: "192.168.45.11"
   #router.vm.box_url = "192.168.45.11"
   #router.vm.boot_timeout = 200
   #router.vagrant.host = "192.168.45.11"
   #router.ssh.host = "192.168.45.11"
 end

#non working 
sowen@pv-sowen-nb:~/Code/flatmate-firewall$ vagrant ssh-config r
Host r
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2222
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /Users/sowen/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
```

Running `vagrant up` hangs part way through the boot process, causing me to have to wait 300 seconds for each vm to boot.

The error message

```
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period. This can
mean a number of things.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.
```

Is there a way to configure `vagrant ssh` to use the correct ip & port so that it doesn't time out?

Source : https://github.com/spuder/flatmate-firewall/blob/master/Vagrantfile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can see your problem in your Vagrantfile, but I show you my example with two machine.

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  # All Vagrant configuration is done here. The most common configuration
  # options are documented and commented below. For a complete reference,
  # please see the online documentation at vagrantup.com.

  config.vm.define 'app' do |app_config|
    app_config.vm.box = 'ubuntu_app'
    app_config.vm.host_name = 'app'
    app_config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.33"
  end

  config.vm.define 'web' do |web_config|
    web_config.vm.box = 'ubuntu_app'
    web_config.vm.host_name = 'web'
    web_config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.34"
  end
end
```

And then I connect to the "web" machine with the standard ssh conection

```
roberto@rcisla-pc:~/Desktop/vagrant$ ssh vagrant@web -p 22
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Welcome to your Vagrant-built virtual machine.
Last login: Sun Jan 12 13:18:18 2014 from 192.168.33.1
vagrant@web:~$
```

equal with the "app machine"

```
roberto@rcisla-pc:~/Desktop/vagrant$ ssh vagrant@app -p 22
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
Welcome to your Vagrant-built virtual machine.
Last login: Sun Jan 12 13:18:18 2014 from 192.168.33.1
vagrant@app:~$
```

I hope this help.

Comment: I'm curious, what's your reason for configuring two vms in one Vagrantfile?