# Can't `ssh` onto Private Network

Tags: ssh, vagrant

Given the following Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "centos_64"
  config.vm.host_name = 'web'
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
end
```

Why can't I ssh onto the guest from the host?

```
$ ssh vagrant@web -p 22
ssh: connect to host web port 22: Connection timed out
```

But using `vagrant ssh` works:

```
$ vagrant ssh
Last login: Tue Mar  4 21:29:24 2014 from 10.0.2.2
[vagrant@web ~]$
```

As expected, I can ping the IP Address from the guest. But I can't ping from the host.

I'm confused as to why it's happening since my setup does not look different from this [configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941224/vagrant-how-to-configure-vagrant-ssh-when-using-private-interfaces).

Comment: you've got a specific network configured in vagrant. Are you sure that plain at-the-prompt ssh is using the same network?

Comment: no, I'm not sure. could you please tell me how to know?

Answer (score 4):

First, `vagrant ssh` uses the forwarded port and not the private network address. You can get the configuration with `vagrant ssh-config`.

Is the name "web" really resolving to the specified IP? Can you ping/connect using the IP instead of the name? If not, verify that you don't have other VMs or external networks with the same address. Also some VPN products mess up the routing.

Comment: I had the same problem and VPN was the cause indeed.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to change the ssh address with

```
config.ssh.host = '192.168.0.13'
config.ssh.port = '22'`
```

as mentioned in https://superuser.com/questions/920536/how-to-change-the-ssh-host-in-vagrantfile/921728#921728

Answer (score 0):

Just because the guest host has a defined hostname does not mean that the host machine will resolve its ip.

You should be able to ssh into the machine by doing:

```
ssh vagrant@192.168.50.4   <====  vagrant is the default password,
```

but you can avoid typing it alway by doing:

```
ssh-copy-id vagrant@192.168.50.4
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my configuration and it's working for me

```
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.88.88"
  config.ssh.host = "192.168.88.88"
```